# Storing the result of an implicit cast to a concrete type into an interface fails

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I want to implicitly cast an implementation to an interface. I know the C# specification doesn't allow this, and that is fine for my use case.

But when I implicitly cast to a type that does implement the interface, I can't store it in a variable of that interface. And that surprises me.

These are the definitions:

```cs
    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
    }

    public class SomeImplementation : ISomeInterface
    {
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public static implicit operator SomeImplementation(Class1 class1)
        {
            return new SomeImplementation();
        }
    }

    var class1 = new Class1();

    // Works
    SomeImplementation s1 = class1;

    // Works
    ISomeInterface i1 = s1;

    // This is what I want to do
    ISomeInterface i2 = class1;
    // Cannot implicitly convert type 'Class1' to 'ISomeInterface'.
    // An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I would expect this to compile, because it is possible to implicitly cast `Class1` to `SomeImplementation` and `SomeImplementation` implements `ISomeInterface`.

Why isn't this allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Well, in short, that there is no technical reason why the own conversions from / to interfaces are not allowed. The reason is because they open the door to certain scenarios that the language designers did not want to open and for that reason they prohibited them." - for full details see [Conversions (explicit or implicit) and interfaces in C#](http://parsstudent.com/conversions-explicit-or-implicit-and-interfaces-in-c/)

Comment: Also "by design" then. MIcrosoft should be glad I wasn't part of their language design team. Thanks.